# Decrypt AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding with CryptoJS

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, cryptojs, javax.crypto

I generate 128bit `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` key using Java `javax.crypto` API. Here is the algorithm that I use:

```
public static String encryptAES(String data, String secretKey) {
    try {
        byte[] secretKeys = Hashing.sha1().hashString(secretKey, Charsets.UTF_8)
                .toString().substring(0, 16)
                .getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);

        final SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeys, "AES");

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

        final AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();

        final byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));

        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(iv) + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(cipherText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
}


public static String decryptAES(String data, String secretKey) {
    try {
        byte[] secretKeys = Hashing.sha1().hashString(secretKey, Charsets.UTF_8)
                .toString().substring(0, 16)
                .getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);

        // grab first 16 bytes - that's the IV
        String hexedIv = data.substring(0, 32);

        // grab everything else - that's the cipher-text (encrypted message)
        String hexedCipherText = data.substring(32);

        byte[] iv = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexedIv);
        byte[] cipherText = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexedCipherText);

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(secretKeys, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), Charsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Secret key is invalid");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
}
```

I can easily encrypt and decrypt messages using secretKey with these methods. Since Java has 128bit AES encryption by default, it generates a hash of the original secret key with SHA1 and takes the first 16-bytes of the hash to use it as secret key in AES. Then it dumps the IV and cipherText in HEX format.

For example `encryptAES("test", "test")` generates `CB5E759CE5FEAFEFCC9BABBFD84DC80C0291ED4917CF1402FF03B8E12716E44C` and I want to decrypt this key with CryptoJS.

Here is my attempt:

```
var str = 'CB5E759CE5FEAFEFCC9BABBFD84DC80C0291ED4917CF1402FF03B8E12716E44C';

CryptJS.AES.decrypt( 
CryptJS.enc.Hex.parse(str.substring(32)),
CryptJS.SHA1("test").toString().substring(0,16),  
{
  iv: CryptJS.enc.Hex.parse(str.substring(0,32)),
  mode: CryptJS.mode.CBC,
  formatter: CryptJS.enc.Hex, 
  blockSize: 16,  
  padding: CryptJS.pad.Pkcs7 
}).toString()
```

However it returns an empty string.

Comment: Java code is `PKCS5Padding`, but JS code is `pad.Pkcs7`. 5 and 7 are not the same.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it's the same: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/13022

Comment: @ArtjomB. Always fun to get a link to an answer saying *"PKCS#5 padding can not be used for AES"* as proof that 5 and 7 are interchangeable for AES.

Comment: @Andreas It's a relic of the naming convention for Java. It just stayed from the DES days. If you look further you will see that `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` also doesn't make sense, because ECB is not applicable to RSA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a 64 bit key as a 128 bit. `Hashing.sha1().hashString(secretKey, Charsets.UTF_8)` is an instance of [`HashCode`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashCode.html) and its `toString` method is described as such:

> Returns a string containing each byte of asBytes(), in order, as a two-digit unsigned hexadecimal number in lower case.

It is a Hex-encoded string. If you take only 16 characters of that string and use it as a key, you only have 64 bits of entropy and not 128 bits. You really should be using `HashCode#asBytes()` directly.

---

Anyway, the problem with the CryptoJS code is manyfold:

- The ciphertext must be a `CipherParams` object, but it is enough if it contains the ciphertext bytes as a WordArray in the `ciphertext` property.
- The key must be passed in as a WordArray instead of a string. Otherwise, an OpenSSL-compatible (EVP_BytesToKey) key derivation function is used to derive the key and IV from the string (assumed to be a password).
- Additional options are either unnecessary, because they are defaults, or they are wrong, because the blockSize is calculated in words and not bytes.

Here is CryptoJS code that is compatible with your broken Java code:

```js
var str = 'CB5E759CE5FEAFEFCC9BABBFD84DC80C0291ED4917CF1402FF03B8E12716E44C';

console.log("Result: " + CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(str.substring(32))
}, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.SHA1("test").toString().substring(0,16)),  
{
  iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(str.substring(0,32)),
}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

Here is CryptoJS code that is compatible with the fixed Java code:

```js
var str = 'F6A5230232062D2F0BDC2080021E997C6D07A733004287544C9DDE7708975525';

console.log("Result: " + CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(str.substring(32))
}, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(CryptoJS.SHA1("test").toString().substring(0,32)),  
{
  iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(str.substring(0,32)),
}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

The equivalent encryption code in CryptoJS would look like this:

```js
function encrypt(plaintext, password){
    var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(CryptoJS.SHA1(password).toString().substring(0,32));
    var ct = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, { iv: iv });
    return iv.concat(ct.ciphertext).toString();
}

console.log("ct: " + encrypt("plaintext", "test"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

Comment: I modified the code as follows: `Arrays.copyOfRange(Hashing.sha1().hashString(secretKey, Charsets.UTF_8).asBytes(), 0, 16)`, as you said, it now generates different hash but in CryptoJS I still get an empty string. Here is an example output of `encryptAES("test", "test")` `F6A5230232062D2F0BDC2080021E997C6D07A733004287544C9DDE7708975525`

Comment: Thanks, now it works as expected! The reason that I used HashCode.toString() is string representation of SHA1 is same in both Java and Javascript. Why do you think that Java code is broken right now?

Comment: The Java code is broken, because it uses only a 64 bit key (16 hexits). Nowadays, such a key is in the realm of brute-forcing even for private individuals.

Comment: What would be your suggestion that would work with CryptoJS? I limit the secret key to 128bit because Java enforces that limit. In order to use 256bit I need to install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files to JRE folder but it's not an option for me because I can't force the clients to install those files manually into their JRE folder which probably requires root permission.

Comment: You're limiting the key to 16 hexits, which are not really 128 bit, but rather 64 bit in disguise. As I suggest in the first part of my answer. You should use the hash bytes directly as you did in [your first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368710/decrypt-aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-with-cryptojs/37368832#comment62250447_37368832). It was the fix is was talking about. Everything is fine now, is it not?

Comment: Ah, I'm not good at encodings, now I get it. I assume 128 bit enough for a safe key, right?

Comment: Yes, 128 bit is perfectly fine now, but not enough once quantum computers are here.

Comment: Thanks @Artjom, you were really helpful!

Comment: @artjom-b can you please provide crypto-js encrypt example!

Comment: @Raja There you go.

Comment: @artjom-b Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This one perfectly worked for me

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';    
const SECRET_CREDIT_CARD_KEY = '1231231231231231' // 16 digits key
    
    decrypt(cipherText) {
        const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(this.SECRET_CREDIT_CARD_KEY);
        const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.SECRET_CREDIT_CARD_KEY);
        const result = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherText, key,
          {
            iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
          }
          )
          const final  = result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
          return final
      }
    
    console.log(decrypt('your encrypted text'))
```

using this library in Angular 8
https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js